# element1: not found in shell unix with arrays

Tags: arrays, unix, ksh

I've got a problem, when i create an array in unix and put this one in a while condition, it not results.. the error is:`element1: not found`. The code:

```
listArr=""
listArr=$listArr"element1\n"
listArr=$listArr"element2\n"
listArr=$listArr"element3\n"
listArr=$listArr"element4\n"
listArr=$listArr"element5\n"
listArr=$listStr"element6"   
arryIdx=0
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=";"
set -A array $(echo $listArr| tr "\n" ";")
IFS=$OLD_IFS    
echo "$listArr"
echo "Elements: " ${#array[*]}
while [ $arryIdx -lt ${#array[*]} ]; 
do  
    ${array[$arryIdx]}
    (( arryIdx= $arryIdx+ 1 ))
done
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: There's a space missing in `$arryIdx-lt`.

Comment: ooh come on -1 for missing space? anyway even with the space gets the same error.

Comment: `$listStr` has to be `$listArr`.

Comment: You deserve at least -1 for not pasting the real code.

Comment: Seems like an odd way to set up an array - why not just `set -A array element1 element2 element3 ...` instead of the whole "create a variable with newline delimiters, translate the newlines to semicolons, and then fiddle with IFS to make `set` interpret that as an array" thing...?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the line `${array[$arryIdx]}` - obviously there is no command `element1` etc. Perhaps you forgot an `echo` in front of it.

Comment: well thank you! It's about two days i can't find this stupid error. Thanks

Comment: ksh -x _yourScript_ can be helpful in such cases.